# How to run sbt assembly on a module without test

Tags: module, sbt

I want to launch the following command and skip tests

```
sbt "project myModlule" clean assembly
```

I know this one for the full project

```
sbt 'set test in assembly := {}' clean assembly
```

But I don't know how to mix them in order to take into account just one module (myModule).
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Won't this work? sbt "project myModlule" "set test in assembly := {}" clean assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to João Guitana who gave the anwser

```
sbt "project myModlule" "set test in assembly := {}" clean assembly
```